# How to run while loops in different threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm playing around with threads for a project I'm working on. I want the methods loop1 and loop2 to run concurrently so the output is "121212121212121212121212121212".

```
public class threadTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        threadOne.start();
        threadTwo.start();
    }
    static Thread threadOne = new Thread() {
        public void loop1() {
            while(true) {
                System.out.println("1");
            }
        }
    };
    static Thread threadTwo = new Thread() {
        public void loop2() {
            while(true) {
                System.out.println("2");
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: You need to rename `loop1` and `loop2` to `run` in the thread objects. Threads need to override `public void run()` in order to have custom behavior.

Comment: If you want them to alternate exactly like that, then you should just run them on one thread. Otherwise, you're going to spend a lot of effort getting the two threads so synchronize their actions, with the end result that exactly one thread is going to be doing work at any given time -- which defeats the whole purpose of having multiple threads.